# iOS Swift - Why does clicking on 1 button activate another button when 1 button overlays the other

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a card app and I am confused about why something is happening. Basically, if you look at the image below, I have three **buttons**. As you can see, the one on the right **overlays** **some of** the other two and the one in the middle overlays **some of** the one on the left. This leaves space for the user to click on the buttons in the middle and on the left. For some reason, when I click the one in the middle OR the one on the left, it activates the one on the right. **I have done nothing to these buttons with code**, except make an IBOutlet and IBAction that only prints "done" to the console. I don't know why it is doing this. Can someone please tell me why this is doing this, and if you can, give me code that code fix this.

[image: Image of the three buttons (cards) overlaying each other]

Comment: Sorry if there is a screenshot, it is just very hard to explain this without a screenshot.

Comment: Did you perhaps copy the first button to create the other two after you hooked up the action?  You probably have multiple actions associated with your buttons.  Control-click on the buttons in IB and look at the connections.

Comment: Ah, silly me. Yeah your right.

Comment: If the problem was trivially solved as a "typo", please delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the different buttons aren't linked to the same IBAction

As @DuncanC suggested in his comment, it could also be a problem of having multiple actions linked to the same button.

Check the connections in the "Connections inspector" of your storyboard.

Comment: Sounds like, more precisely, some of the buttons have **multiple** actions, which is something readers may not even be aware is possible.

Comment: Like @DuncanC says also check if the buttons aren't linked to multiple actions. In the connections inspector of your storyboard.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to suggest that, so other readers of your answer know to check that without having to also read the comments. Remember this sight is at least as useful to other readers with the problem as it is for the OP (original poster.)